# Why are sutural bones more common in lambdoid suture?

Tags: human-anatomy, embryology, bone-biology

Why are sutural bones (Wormian bones) are more commonly present at lambdoid suture? Is the tortuous nature of lambdoid suture a reason for that?

---

Evidences for my claim:

> They(sutural bones) **occur most frequently** in the course of the **lambdoid suture**, which is **more tortuous** than other sutures. They are also occasionally seen within the sagittal and coronal sutures. (1)

---

> They are **commonly found in the lambdoid suture** and fontanelles but are occasionally seen in other sutures especially the coronal, squamosal, and sagittal sutures. We examined 25 dried human skulls with the aim to find out the occurrence and variations of Wormian bones, and surprisingly we found Wormian bones in the coronal, squamosal, and sagittal sutures in 6 skulls. These are uncommon sites of occurrence of sutural bones as reported in the literature. These findings prompted us to report these cases as their presence can lead to confusion in diagnosis in cases of skull fractures.(2)

---

Sources:

1- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormian_bones

2- https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22117248

Comment: Is the question now more clear?